# Problems when ending a GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: game-center

I've been testing my turn based game app on two devices.
When device 1 quits (by swiping and deleting the match from GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController) , it updates device 2 to show that the match has been done (yet it still shows in GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController that the match is Other Player's Turn), but device 1 doesn't update!

It says in GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController under Game Over section the ended match, but says "No Outcome" ,and from apple documentary- The participant’s outcome has not been set yet (typically because the match is still in progress).

I want to know how to set that to something else, and what method is (supposed) to be called by quitting that way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController playerQuitForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {

    if ([match.currentParticipant.playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer        localPlayer].playerID]) {

        [match participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit nextParticipants:nextParticipant turnTimeout:GKTurnTimeoutNone matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

            [match removeWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                //Player quitted and match removed

            }];

        }];

    }
    else {

        [match participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

            [match removeWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

                //Player quitted and match removed

            }];

        }];

    }

}
```

For device 2

```
-(void)handleTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {

    if (player2.matchOutcome==GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit){

        //Your opponent quitted do something

    }

}
```

Comment: When match is over, it doesn't remove that game from sandbox. Can You say how to remove quit games from sandbox

Comment: If match is over or user quitted from that match previously , then just use -removeWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) method.

Comment: Are you sure `turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:playerQuitForMatch:` is called in the swipe-to-remove instance? I'm not seeing that happen in my testing.